# Change margins on selected pages

Tags: graphics, margins

I have an document using the `article` class using the `fullpage` package. The appendices take up the last 15 pages and contain pdf images using the `graphicx` package.

I want to change the margins of these pages so that the pdf images can take up as much space as possible; my top margin is rather large for the main body of the text and is not suitable for the appendices.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: `\newgeometry{}` via the `geometry` package; just put the `\newgeometry{}` command before the appendices.

Comment: @Adam I don't have the geometry package loaded. As soon as I loaded it, it threw the footer up and knocked the page number off centre. I forgot to mention that I am using the fancyhdr package. Is there a way of making the necessary changes with the fanchdr package instead?

Answer (score 1):

You could change the margins with the `geometry` package or simply with a list environment (copy the definition of `quote` but indent by a negative amount) but it isn't necessary and it's usually best not to change the page size in a way that affects the page head and foot.

If you want all your images to be (say) 3cm wider than `\textwidth` bleeding 1.5cm into each margin then you can simply use

```
...

\hspace*{-1.5cm}%
\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\detxtwidth+3cm\relax]{...}%
\hspace*{-1.5cm}%

\caption{...}
```

You don't have to shrink the margins, you can just overlap *into* the existing margins.

Comment: What package do I find `\dimexpr` in?

Comment: it is an etex primitive so built in to the executable, not defined by package code. @HåkonK.Olafsen